# No collision-detection by using SKShapeNode with UIBezierpath

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, uibezierpath, skphysicsbody

I have the following UIBezierPath which is like a circle, but with a gap in it:
[image]

```
var centerPosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
var aPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPosition, radius: 75, startAngle: 0, endAngle: degreesToRadians(size), clockwise: true)
gapeCircle = SKShapeNode(path: myPath, centered: true)
```

Now I'd like to use the SKPhysicsBody so that when an object collides with the outline of this object, that there is a notification. But only in that situation. If the object "collides" at the gap-position, there shouldn't be a notification.

But I couldn't find out how to solve that problem. I've already tried multiple different SKPhysicsBody-initializers. The only one that worked was the `circleOfRadius` but that doesn't work like I want it to work, because I need to check the collision only if an object collides with the "non-gap" part of my circle.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're not using a closed UIBezierPath. The following code will create a curve that loops back on itself giving the 'C' a width of just 1 pt

```
var centerPosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
var aPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPosition, radius: 75, startAngle: 0, endAngle: degreesToRadians(size), clockwise: true)
var aPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPosition, radius: 74, startAngle: degreesToRadians(size), endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
gapeCircle = SKShapeNode(path: myPath, centered: true)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I will check when I'm home.